# F key is not working in android studio, instead creating new flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When I type f key in code its creating new flutter project instead of writing f letter. I could not find a solution please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you created a shortcut key value. which ide do you use?

Comment: Yes I think so but I could not find that shortcut, i was set Intellij, When I change it to vscode now its working thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

My Ide was set Intellij, When I change it to vscode now its working.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

can you try to change the red rectangle section